# __FUNCTION__ expands to an invalid memory address

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I'm struggling with VC++'s [predefined macros.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) As I understand it, `__FUNCTION__` should expand to a string literal during preprocessing. For some reason, when I look at this address it expands to, the memory is invalid/arbitrary/uninitialized. However, if I call a function and then use `__FUNCTION__` in **that** frame, it works.

For example, I have this segment of test code:

```
#if (MODE == USER_MODE)
    PCSTR test = __FUNCTION__;
#endif
```

In WinDbg:

```
0: kd> ?? test
char * 0x00007ff9`a08a7e30
 "--- memory read error at address 0x00007ff9`a08a7e30 ---"
0: kd> db 0x00007ff9`a08a7e60
00007ff9`a08a7e60  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
00007ff9`a08a7e70  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
00007ff9`a08a7e80  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
00007ff9`a08a7e90  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
00007ff9`a08a7ea0  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
00007ff9`a08a7eb0  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
00007ff9`a08a7ec0  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
00007ff9`a08a7ed0  ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??-?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??  ????????????????
```

If I then immediately call a function and try it from within there:

```
#if (MODE == USER_MODE)
    PCSTR test = __FUNCTION__;
#endif

DavidsTestFunction();

return;
}

VOID
__declspec(noreturn)
DavidsTestFunction()
{
    #if (MODE == USER_MODE)
        PCSTR test = __FUNCTION__;
    #endif    
}
```

Then it works as expected:

```
0: kd> ?? test
char * 0x00007ff9`a089c470
"DavidsTestFunction"
```

I'm completely stumped. The only thing I can imagine is that it's because we have some shenanigans around the function name. For example, since we call this function from an inline stub, the function name is changed by a macro to append "imp_" to it by something like this.

```
#define OUREXPORTFUNCTION(a) imp_ ## a

...

OUREXPORTFUNCTION(DavidsInitialFunction) () {

    ...

}
```

However I can't see why that would effect it and it's not something I'm able to change to test. Any ideas?

Comment: The memory is paged out. kd cannot see memory that is paged out. Use ntsd, cdb, or windbg instead.

Comment: This was using WinDbg. I passed this to a function as a parameter and accessed it to ensure it was paged in, and had the same result.

Comment: Your example is not clear. You seem to be showing the use of `__FUNCTION__` outside of a function.

Comment: That's just the relevant part of the code. It is indeed inside a function (although a function whose name gets defined by a macro, if that matters).

Comment: It *might* be due to using a macro to define the function name. It doesn't quite make sense that `__FUNCTION__` is actually considered a macro though, since macro expansion "should" entirely take place before any syntactical parsing (i.e. finding functions). It's also possible that it's trying to use `"OUREXPORTFUNCTION"` as the name, but because it's a macro, the string disappears?

Comment: You are using windbg in kd mode. Note that the prompt is `kd>`. Use windbg in user mode.

Comment: Furthermore, the two `__FUNCTION__`s you are passing are different. The one that is paged out is `0x00007ff9``a08a7e30`. The one that is paged in is `0x00007ff9``a089c470`. Nothing here is unexpected.

Comment: I tried a .pagein (a command I'm not particularly familiar with) on the memory, and it didn't quite work as I had hoped. I'll try in the morning with a user mode debugger, and if that is the issue (which I really hope it is!) you should add it as an answer for me to accept :)

Comment: You were right! Compiler kept out smarting me in terms of using the string literal, but assigning one of the letters to a volatile char did the trick.